# Adjoint functors diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I'd like to improve the following diagram for a pair of adjoint functors:
[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \mathcal{D}\arrow[r, shift left=.75ex, "G"{name=G}] & \mathcal{C}\arrow[l, shift left=.75ex, "F"{name=F}] 
            \arrow[phantom, from=F, to=G, "\dashv" rotate=90].      
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Is there a standard diagram for a pair of adjoint functors?

Comment: It is also not entirely clear (at least to me) what you're asking. The diagram looks fine as far as I can tell, so is it the code usde to create it that you would like to improve?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've just done it. I'd like to improve how the diagram looks, e.g. maybe making the `\dashv` symbol a bit smaller (?).

Comment: To make it smaller you could replace `\dashv` by either `\scriptstyle\dashv` or `\scriptscriptstyle\dashv`.

Comment: It is really hard to answer this question because it is not clear what "improve" means. Some might bend the arrows, some may make the symbol smaller, some may add colors and others may add ducks. Could you perhaps add a sketch of the desired outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? I use `\top` in the place of a rotated `\dashv`·

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}

\begin{document}

    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \D\arrow[r, shift left=1ex, "G"{name=G}] & \C\arrow[l, shift left=.5ex, "F"{name=F}]
            \arrow[phantom, from=F, to=G, , "\scriptscriptstyle\boldsymbol{\top}"].
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Peraphs (but from the initial picture it is not very clear) the `\top` is written in bold. However you have always my appreciations.

Comment: @Sebastiano: maybe it depends on the font. Anyway, I tested with `\boldsymbol` and indeed, it looks better from my point of  view, so I added it to my code Thanks for drawing my attention on this point!

Comment: Yes of course! :-) You colud add also another code with `\intercal` (instead of `\top`) if you want :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano: I didn't think of that (I very seldom use this symbol), but having tested, I find it too heavy, even without \boldsymbol.

Comment: Don't worry about it at all. I always respect the tastes of others. \intercal I has been used simply without bold in my book :-)